# Xcode 4 Interface Building Font Not Updating/Showing

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

When I am changing the font of a label to anything other than the default, the label's font never changes. I can change the font size but not the displaying font. However, when I double click on the label, I can see what the label's font would look like. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: method you described should work. Can you describe more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all fonts are available on the iPhone. If you are setting the font to an unavailable one, it will default to helvetica. Search the net for a list of the fonts you can use.

Comment: Yes but the font I am using, Helvetica Neue is available for selection under Fonts.

Comment: If you can tell the difference between helvetica and helvetica neue, you're a better man than I am :-)

Comment: Seriously though, not all weights of neue are supported and the selector in interface builder comes from the fonts on your mac, not the phone. Try something like marker felt - if this works the you know the problem was that you were using an unsupported font.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference http://iosfonts.com/ for fonts available for each version of iOS.  Fonts outside this list will appear as Helvetica, as jrturton said.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest expanding the size of the text box, by dragging its outermost edges? Despite having made your changes if the selected font/font size combo is to large for the text box to handle it will remain smaller than what you selected even though when you go into the highlight view it appears correct

**Edit**
Just Because its in that font selection tool does not mean it will show up on the device